# Plot pandas.core.series.Series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How can I line plot a `pandas.core.series.Series`?

**Example**:

```
Id  Week
01       36      155
         37      145
         38      207
02       36      116
         37       98
         38       99
03       36       61
         37       29
04       36      162
         37      190
         38      190
05       36       26
         37       35
         38       20
06       36       57
         37       40
         38       15
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

So all id's has one line and Week is the X and num is Y?

I have tried:

```
week.plot(x='Week', y='num')
plt.show()
```

But it is only plotting one line and and `(01, 36) (02, 38) (04, 38)  (06, 37)` at the bottom as X. To make the series, I have used the following:

```
week = df.groupby(['Id', 'Week']).num.count()
```

Here is a code that makes the exact same thing:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
i = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
w = [36, 37, 38]
n = 1
iD = []
wEek = []
nUm = []
for o in range(250):
    iD.append(random.choice(i))
    wEek.append(random.choice(w))
    nUm.append(n)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': iD, 'Week': wEek, 'num': nUm})

week = df.groupby(['Id', 'Week']).num.count()
week.plot()
plt.show()
```

And the plot looks like this:
[The plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw0gU.png)

I want all the `Id`s have one separate line with the value of `num.count()`(Y) for each `Week`(X).

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC I have edit my post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually want 4 different line plots in a same figure for each id with x axis being weeks and y axis being the numeric values:

```
week.unstack(0).plot()
```

If you want each line in different subplot, just add subplots=True arg like this:

```
week.unstack(0).plot(subplots=True)
```

Here, unstack(0) function pivots our multi-indexed series with given level 0 being the leftmost index (Id).

Comment: The unstack did it. But i can't remember that i have used the unstack before but i have made this types of plots before. Maybe time to sleep... :)